# High accuracy in mode.fit but low precision and recall

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've been training a CNN with keras. A binary classificator where it says if a depth image has a manhole or not. I've manually labeled the datasets with 0 (no manhole) and 1 (it has a manhole). I have 2 datasets 1 with 45k images to train the CNN and one with 26k images to test the CNN.

Both datasets are unbalanced double of negatives images than positives.

This is the code:

```
# dimensions of our images.
img_width, img_height = 80, 60
n_positives_img, n_negatives_img = 17874, 26308 
n_total_img = 44182

#Labeled arrays for datasets
arrayceros = np.zeros(n_negatives_img)
arrayunos = np.ones(n_positives_img)

#Reshaping of datasets to convert separate them
arraynegativos= ds_negatives.reshape(( n_negatives_img, img_height, img_width,1))
arraypositivos= ds_positives.reshape((n_positives_img, img_height, img_width,1))

#Labeling datasets with the arrays
ds_negatives_target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arraynegativos, arrayceros))
ds_positives_target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((arraypositivos, arrayunos))

#Concatenate 2 datasets and shuffle them
ds_concatenate = ds_negatives_target.concatenate(ds_positives_target)
datasetfinal = ds_concatenate.shuffle(n_total_img)
```

Then I have the same for the second dataset for testing.

```
#Adding batch dimension to datasets 4dim
valid_ds = datasetfinal2.batch(12)
train_ds = datasetfinal.batch(12)

#Defining model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(5, kernel_size=(5, 5),activation='relu',input_shape=(60,80,1),padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D((5, 5),padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2),padding='same'))
model.add(Dropout(0.3))
model.add(Conv2D(5, (5, 5), activation='relu',padding='same'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

#Compiling model
model.summary()

initial_learning_rate = 0.001
lr_schedule = keras.optimizers.schedules.ExponentialDecay(
    initial_learning_rate, decay_steps=100000, decay_rate=0.96, staircase=True
)
model.compile(
    loss="binary_crossentropy",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=lr_schedule),
    metrics=["acc"],
)

# Define callbacks.
checkpoint_cb = keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    "2d_image_classification.h5", save_best_only=True
)
early_stopping_cb = keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="val_acc", patience=15)

#Fitting the model
history= model.fit(train_ds, validation_data=valid_ds, batch_size=100, epochs=5,callbacks=[checkpoint_cb, early_stopping_cb])
```

This gives me 99% of acc in train dataset and 95% in test dataset.
But when i do this it gives me 60% precision for negatives images and 45% for positives:

```
#Get the real labels of valid dataset
valid_labels = list(valid_ds.flat_map(lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))).as_numpy_iterator())
valid_labels = [y for x, y in valid_labels]

y_pred = model.predict(valid_ds)
y_pred = (y_pred > 0.5).astype(float)

from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
print(classification_report(valid_labels, y_pred))
```

Why this? I have printed both predicted labels and true labels and it look likes its random. It has no sense.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1bhrntDItqoeT0KLb-aKp0W8cV6LOQOtP?usp=sharing

If u need more information, just ask me.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: This question might be better off on https://datascience.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ill post it there also so. Thanks! Didnt know the existence of that!

Comment: can you share your dataset?

Comment: this is the link to my datasets in drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/15SzT4CY6-njS-EIxhCBjpX7XVS6jVtCy/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FDR8Hh8UAyCnGLNNidRprv-ntcJUPmp2/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FtNKwxvd5O-lo8fRGlwIbhztjPhsU6ld/view?usp=sharing, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UaCSEn0X3J-2FAZcrfu7RIcVUJlb-Rsa/view?usp=sharing